# Why is sqrt() working with int argument?

Tags: c++, int, cmath

I'm self-study the book "*Programming principles and practice Using C++*" by Bjarne Stroustrup (2008). I faced a small problem when I implementation a practice from the book. The IDE used here is Visual Studio 2012 ultimate. The project type used here is Win32 Console Application.

On the page 68 of the book, the author claims:

“*Note that sqrt() is not defined for an int so assign n to a double and take sqrt() of that*”

However, I found it is not conform to my practice code as fowling:

```
// test if sqrt() a integer is working
#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"

int main ()
{
    int a = 10;
    cout << "square root of 10 is " << sqrt(a) << endl;
    keep_window_open();

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
square root of 10 is 3.16228
Please enter a character to exit
```

Question:

Why it is working as I did the way that the book told no to? Or, I got the wrong understanding of “*sqrt() is not defined for an int*”, if so what is the right way to interpreter it?