# sqrt() - Why am I allowed to provide an argument of int and not only double and the output is also right?

Tags: c, int, arguments, language-lawyer, sqrt

I wondering why the compiler let this pass and is giving the right output, although `sqrt()` from its prototype normally should only get an `double` value as argument:

In C99 the declaration of the prototype is:

> double sqrt  (double x);

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (void)
{  
   int i = 9;

   printf("\t Number \t\t Square Root of Number\n\n");

   printf("\t %d \t\t\t %f \n",i, sqrt(i)); 

}
```

Output:

```
 Number      Square Root of Number

 9           3.000000
```

Why does the compiler not throw a warning at least and the given output is right, if I´m giving the `sqrt()` function an `int` as argument?

Is this crossing into Undefined Behavior?

I´m using gcc.

---

The Question was already asked twice for C++, but not for C, so my question is up for C.
I provide the links to the questions for C++ anyway:

[Why does sqrt() work fine on an int variable if it is not defined for an int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19613191/why-does-sqrt-work-fine-on-an-int-variable-if-it-is-not-defined-for-an-int)

[Why is sqrt() working with int argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19684441/why-is-sqrt-working-with-int-argument)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not undefined behavior.

The function is defined to accept an argument of type `double`.  Because the type of the argument is known, you can pass an `int` because it may be implicitly converted to a `double`.  It's the same as if you did:

```
int i = 4;
double d = i;
```

The rules for conversion of function arguments are spelled out in section 6.5.2.2p7 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding the function call operator `()`:

> If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that
>   does include a prototype, **the arguments are implicitly converted, as
>   if by assignment, to the types of the corresponding parameters, taking
>   the type of each parameter to be the unqualified version of its
>   declared type.** The ellipsis notation in a function prototype
>   declarator causes argument type conversion to stop after the last
>   declared parameter. The default argument promotions are performed on
>   trailing arguments

In contrast, if you passed an `int` to `printf` when the format string expects a `double`, i.e.:

```
printf("%f\n", 4);
```

Then you have undefined behavior.  This is because the types of the arguments are not known at compile time so the implicit conversion can't happen.

Comment: Thank you very much. And also my desired citation of the standard. Thank you very much for your efforts. I have one question more: Does this also work with a `char`? Like f.e. when i take your example: `char c = 4;
double d = c;` or as in my given example: `printf("\t %d \t\t\t %f \n",i, sqrt(c));` Or does that only applies to the conversion from `int` to `double`?

Comment: @RobertS-ReinstateMonica A `char` can be implicitly converted to a `double` as well.  In addition, a `char` can be **promoted** to an `int` in places where an `int` can be used.  This includes being an argument to `printf`, so you can pass a `char` value with a `%d` format specifier.